# Replacing only certain characters in a string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following column:

| Document_Number |
| --- |
| FIN-0582 |
| FIN-7624 |
| CKS-584202 |
| CKS-891026 |

As can be seen above, there are two formats in this column: One beginning with 'FIN-' followed by 4 characters, while the other starts with 'CKS-' followed by 6 characters.

I need to change the 'CKS-' format into the same as 'FIN-', by taking only the last 4 characters from the right.

The expected result would look like this:

| Document_Number |
| --- |
| FIN-0582 |
| FIN-7624 |
| FIN-4202 |
| FIN-1026 |

I have tried using the replace function, but I don't know what to do after this:

```
SET Document_Number = replace(Document_Number, 'CKS', 'FIN')
```

Comment: So you don't know how to do positional character replacement and how to search for it? Try searching for "sql server string functions" in your favorite search engine, find the search result from Microsoft  and then go through the list of functions.  Hint: check "SUBSTRING " first.

Comment: @Alex don't actually need `substring` - `right` is more efficient... but same principle :)

Comment: @enzoAustin how did you get on? You have answers below

Answer (score 1):

You want the *right* most 4 digits... use the [`RIGHT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/right-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) function.

```
select
  'FIN-' + right(Document_Number, 4) Document_Number
from (
  values
  ('CKS-584202')
  , ('FIN-7624')
) x (Document_Number);
```

Returns

| Document_Number |
| --- |
| FIN-4202 |
| FIN-7624 |